# NGINX 1.1.3.3/Debian 8 - custom installation, client_temp a file rather than a directory

Tags: nginx, configuration, cache

I've run into a weird issue.  I have a custom configured and compiled version of NGINX (I wanted a couple extra compile time modules installed).  For whatever reason, it's creating `client_temp` as a file rather than a directory, and that's causing a 500 internal server error whenever I try uploading a file.

My configuration:

```
--prefix=/opt/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx 
--conf-path=/opt/nginx/nginx.conf 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=www-data --group=www-data 
--with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-threads --with-file-aio 
--with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module 
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector 
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=native' --add-module=../ngx_cache_purge-2.3 
--add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=../ModSecurity-nginx
```

As you can see, I do specify a path for `client_temp`: `--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp`, yet it's a file rather than a directory.

Do I need to manually create `client_temp` as a directory and remove the file?  Or is there another way to remedy the situation?

Comment: Create the directory first, and set any permission as needed.  Then try it.

Comment: That did the trick!  I'll upvote/mark as answer if you wish to turn the comment into an answer post

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I have answered the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, its sometimes easier/better to create the `client_temp` directory first, and set its permissions/ownership, and *then* launch the Nginx service.  This will insure the folder exists, and its permissions set is appropriate for accepting uploaded files.